# adding another key-value with rails response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a property. A property has many rooms. Each room have many photos. So when getting all rooms for this property I want each room to have an extra array field with the images for that room for easy handling later in view.

```
@property=Property.find(params[:id])
#initialized array for calculations
    @rooms=[]
#creates a photos key as array value 
    @property.rooms.each do |room|
      room=room
#for saving all photos for 1 room
      photos=[]
      room.photos.each do |photo|
        photos.push(photo.image_url(:medium))
      end
#create and add a photos key to the room hash
      room[:photos] << photos
#push the room hash to @rooms instance variable
      @rooms.push(room)
    end
```

This is not working

when inspecting i got below error

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute
>   `photos`

Could someone tell me what might be the cause? Is there a better way to do this in rails?

Comment: Is `Room` an `ActiveRecord` model that `belongs_to` `Property`?  If so, does it have a `photos` attribute/column?

Comment: yes. But there is no photos column/attribute. There is one table Photo. Room has_many :photos and each photo belongs_to :room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. The issue was that the result i get from active record is not a plain hash instead a model instance. So for adding attributes I converted it to json and then added a new key-value and now it worked as expected.

```
#initialized array for calculations
    @rooms=[]
    #for each creates a photos key as array value
    @property.rooms.each do |room|
#for saving all photos for 1 room
      photos=[]
      room.photos.each do |photo|
        photos.push(photo.image_url(:medium))
      end

      room=room.as_json

#create and add a photos key to the room hash
      room['photos']= photos
#push the room hash to @rooms instance variable
      @rooms.push(room.as_json)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to loop through `rooms` and `photos` manually. Instead, establish the relationship in the model:

```
# app/models/property.rb
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
  # ...
end

# app/models/room.rb
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property, inverse_of :rooms
  has_many :photos
  # ...
end

# app/models/photo.rb
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room, inverse_of :photos
  # ...
end
```

With this, you'll be able to use dot notation:

```
@property.rooms[0].photos # all the photos of the first room
```

Comment: This is the same code I have basically.  To get photos for each room and save it to an attribute I need to loop through each room. In your example you fetch only the photos for the first room which is not what I want. Actually my question is entirely different. for each image I need to run photo.image_url(:medium) to get the proper url. then for each room a new photos field need to be created. This is not for saving in database but only for use in view. The issue is am unable to add      room[:photos] << photos to room